# Solving an equation with both linear and exponential terms

Tags: problem-solving, exponential-function

Can I find an algebraic solution for the equation below? Thank you.

$$
x+e^{x}(x+a)=b
$$

Comment: More likely, there is no elementary approach for this type of problem.  You can use Newton's method, which determines the approximated solutions of $x$.  Other than that, I don't think there is a clean way to determine the answer.

Comment: @NasuSama Thank you so much!

Comment: The solution can be expressed in terms of Lambert W function: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2545838

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $x + e^x (x + a) = b$ is [transcendental](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalEquation.html), and, unfortunately, in this case there is no closed formula for $x$. This equation can be written as
$$e^x = \frac{b - x}{x + a},$$
so it should be clear that one cannot solve it analytically.

Answer (score 0):

As already said by other comments and answers, the equation is transcendental and there is no closed formula for the solution. Only numerical methods (such as Newton) would provide a solution.

By the way, the equation can look "nicer" if you define $x+a=y$.